# Tag wiki edit history

Tags: support, tags, editing, tag-wiki

Unlike questions or answers, tag wikis do not seem to have an “Active” view. Editing a tag wiki does not seem to “bump it,” to my knowledge. The 10k tools have a “new tags” area, but that seems to be for *recently created* tags.

**Is there any way, whether through a site tool or SEDE query, to see which tag wikis or excerpts have recently been edited?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is easy enough to obtain via SEDE: http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/539010/last-active-tag-wikis

```
select top 100 concat('site://tags/', Tags.TagName, '/info|', Tags.TagName, ' tag wiki') "Recently-active tag wikis", p.LastActivityDate
from Tags
join Posts p on p.Id=Tags.WikiPostId
order by p.LastActivityDate desc
```

This just retrieves the last 100 active wikis (based on activity date, which will *normally* be the same as last edit date), ordered by last activity date.  The funky `concat(...` serves to create a clickable link in SEDE, which is nice to have.

Feel free to adjust this query to meet your needs...

Comment: Of course, the usual Data.SE caveat applies here: the database is only updated once a week, so we can only see which tag wikis were active most recently *up to the previous Sunday*.